# Is there a panda equivalent to tribble?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write unit test for python declaring some simple data frames. 
Is there a panda equivalent to the R [tribble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html). For example :

```
tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  "a",   1,
  "b",   2,
  "c",   3
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   colA   colB
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         2
#> 3 c         3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own `tribble` function:

```
def tribble(columns, *data):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=list(zip(*[iter(data)]*len(columns))),
        columns=columns
    )
```

Then you can use it like:

```
tribble(
    ['colA', 'colB'],
    'a', 1,
    'b', 2,
    'c', 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
>>> from datar import f
>>> from datar.tibble import tribble
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...   f.colA, f.colB,
...   "a",    1,
...   "b",    2,
...   "c",    3
... )
>>> df
      colA    colB
  <object> <int64>
0        a       1
1        b       2
2        c       3
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.